# MYSQL ERROR when submitting form

Tags: php, mysql, forms

Hi I'm having some problems when I'm trying to submit a form of mine, everything seems to look fine on my end but im not quite sure why it's still not working any help would be appreciated.

**config.php**

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "release";
$password = "";
$dbname = "release";

// Create connection
$con = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 


?>
```

**submit.php**

```
<?php
include('config.php');

$producers = $_POST['producers'];
$company = $_POST['company'];
$title = $_POST['title'];

if(!$producers or !$company or !$title) {
    echo 'Please make sure to fill out all required feilds.';
} else {
// Insert into DB
$sql = "INSERT INTO release (id, producers, company, title)
VALUES ('null', '$producers', '$company', '$title')";
}

if ($con->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $con->error;
}$con->close();
?>
```

index.php

```
<html>
<head>
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
<link href="css/bootstrap-responsive.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.8.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<style>
input[type="text"] {
    height: 30px;
    }
</style>
<title>RRP &raquo; Welcome!</title>
</head>

<body>
<div style="width: 1080px; margin-top: 50px;">
<h3>Welcome!</h3>
<h4>You can edit the basic release form info below. <br /> Once done hit the "Submit" button to carry on to the new form!</h4>

<div class="container">
      <form class="contact-us form-horizontal" action="submit.php" method="post">      
        <div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label">Producers</label>
            <div class="controls">
                <div class="input-prepend">
                <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-user"></i></span>
                    <input type="text" class="input-xlarge" name="producers" placeholder="Producers(seperate by commas)">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

            <div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label">Production Company</label>
            <div class="controls">
                <div class="input-prepend">
                <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-globe"></i></span>
                    <input type="text" class="input-xlarge" name="company" placeholder="Rolling Ridges Productions">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

            <div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label">Title</label>
            <div class="controls">
                <div class="input-prepend">
                <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-pencil"></i></span>
                    <input type="text" class="input-xlarge" name="title" placeholder="Desperate Measures">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

         <div class="control-group">
          <div class="controls">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn">Cancel</button>
          </div>    
        </div>
      </form>
</body>
</html>
```

error

```
Error: INSERT INTO release (id, producers, company, title) VALUES ('null', 'lol', 'lol', 'lol')
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'release (id, producers, company, title) VALUES ('null', 'lol', 'lol', 'lol')' at line 1
```

**Resolved:** was as simple as adding ticks to `release`

Comment: add your HTML form

Comment: what error showing ?

Comment: Also add mysql error which you see

Comment: did you using AUTO INCREMENT ID ?

Comment: no need to change your table name just use backticks in your table name like this $sql = "INSERT INTO `release` (id, producers, company, title)
VALUES ('null', '$producers', '$company', '$title')";

Comment: @jothi:  Since you gave the answer, you should post it as such.

Answer (score 2):

release is a [MySQL keyword](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/keywords.html), and should be enclosed in backticks: `release`

Comment: it should be in comment area

Answer (score 1):

try to use backticks in table name if it is keyword **`release`**

```
  $sql = "INSERT INTO `release` (id, producers, company, title)
          VALUES ('null', '$producers', '$company', '$title')";
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that `id` should not be assigned the string value `'null'`.  Typically `id` columns are auto increment, in which case you should simply omit the column:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO `release` (producers, company, title)
VALUES ('".addslashes($producers)."', '".addslashes($company)."', '".addslashes($title)."'";
```

The `addslashes` is to protect again [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). You should also sanitize your inputs:

```
$producers = strval($_POST['producers']);
$company = strval($_POST['company']);
$title = strval($_POST['title']);
```

Answer (score 0):

Also it is better to write your database in the following format
database name  -> **db_name** eg **db_release**, and 
table name     -> **tb_name** eg **tb_release**

so as to avoid **keywords** errors

Comment: I personally prefer simple undecorated names, to reduce clutter in my code.

Comment: yaah it is not so bad, but i advise you to start with db_ or tb_